# Mongoose compare BCRYPT passwords not filled

Tags: typescript, express, mongoose, bcrypt

I am trying to add bcrypt inside the mongoose model using typescript.
I am using [this link](https://github.com/CodAffection/MEAN-Stack-Jwt-Authentication-Node-JS-Part-1/blob/master/server/models/user.model.js) as an example.

But my project is using typescript so i cannot completely use the same code. I do not understand where they are getting the password to do the matching with the user send password from.

When i compare the passwords it seems one of the passwords is undefined.
Below is my code, any help is appreciated.

```
 PersonTestSchema.pre<PersonTestModel>('save', function (next) {
  const user = this;
  if (this.password && this.password.length > 4) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (err, salt) {
      bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
        user.password = hash;
        next();
      });
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

PersonTestSchema.methods.verifyPassword = function (candidatePassword: string) {
  const user = this;
  return bcrypt.compareSync(candidatePassword, user.password);
```

When i log the candidate password it is filled but if i log the user.password it is empty. 
This seems logical in my code but i dont undertand where they are getting it from in their example code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Turns out i had to modify their version of passportConfig file and the best way was to pass along the password from the DB from there